# Creating an array of structs in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I'm working on an assignment that requires me to use an "*array of structs*". I did this once before for another assignment for this prof, using this code:

```
struct monthlyData {
    float rainfall;
    float highTemp; 
    float lowTemp;  
    float avgTemp;  
} month[12];
```

Which got the job done fine, but I got points marked off for the array being global. What should I do instead to avoid that? I haven't touched C++ at all over the summer, so I'm pretty rusty on it at the moment and have no clue where to start for this one.

Comment: Do you have no clue because you don't know of any other kind of variables besides global ones?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply define the struct as:

```
struct monthlyData {
    float rainfall;
    float highTemp; 
    float lowTemp;  
    float avgTemp;  
};
```

And then create an array of this struct, in a function, where you need it:

```
void f() {
    monthlyData month[12];
    //use month
}
```

Now the array is not a global variable. It is a local variable, and you've to pass this variable to other function(s) so that other function(s) can use the **same** array. And here is how you should pass it:

```
void otherFunction(monthlyData *month) {
    // process month
}

void f() {
    monthlyData month[12];
    // use month
    otherFunction(month);
}
```

Note that `otherFunction` assumes that the size of array is `12` (a constant value). If the size can be anything, then you can do this instead:

```
void otherFunction(monthlyData *month, int size) {
    // process month
}

void f() {
    monthlyData month[12];
    // use month
    otherFunction(month, 12); //pass 12 as size
}
```

Answer (score 2):

well, you can have the array declared only inside the method that needs it :)

```
struct monthlyData
{
  float rainfall;
  float highTemp; 
  float lowTemp;  
  float avgTemp;  
};

int main()
{

  monthlyData month[12];

}
```

and if you need to use it also from another method, you pass it around as method parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Declar the struct first

```
struct monthlyData { 
   float rainfall; 
   float highTemp;  
   float lowTemp;   
   float avgTemp;   
};
```

Then use e.g.

```
void foo()
{
   struct monthlyData months[12];
   ....

}
```