# Defining an array of a custom struct type

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I have tried to make an array of a struct I have defined like in [Creating an array of structs in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7239220/creating-an-array-of-structs-in-c) but I get an `no matching function to call to Simplex::simplex()' error. What is going wrong? Underneath is (what I think is) the relevant code. The error is in the Simplex simplices[numberOfSimplices] line.

```
struct Simplex {
public:
    int dimension;
    long* vertices;

    // Constructor definition
    Simplex(int d, long* v) {
        dimension = d;
        vertices = v;
    }
};

void f() {
    // Initializing random seed
    srand(time(NULL));

    long numberOfSimplices = rand() % maxSimplices + 1;

    Simplex simplices[numberOfSimplices];
}
```

Comment: You need to define a default Constructor in your Simplex class, so a constructor without parameters. ````Simplex(){}````

Comment: Or better: use a `std::vector´ instead of an array, then you can add elements that have been created from any non-default constructor.

Comment: That variable-length array isn't supported by the C++ standard anyway, so yet another reason to avoid it and use `std::vector<Simplex>` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Simplex simplices[numberOfSimplices];
```

is going to create `numberOfSimplices` number of `Simplex`'s. Since you don't convey how to create those objects, the assumption is `Simplex` objects are default constructable using `Simplex()`, but there is no default constructor available in `Simplex` class, the only constructor available is `Simplex(int, long*)`